# My microphone doesn't work in Garry's Mod

Tags: steam, garrys-mod

I press the 'Press-To-Talk' key I have set on GMod and it doesn't show my microphone is open to broadcast. I have even reset the binds and nothing worked.

Comment: Does it work in other Games or different software?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't broadcast any sound or doesn't even attempt to broadcast when you press the button? If the latter, try making a bind for +voice_record `bind "X" "+voice_record"`.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure the microphone itself is not broken. not correctly plugged in or the driver not installed. 
if you want to test if the microphone works try using Skype if you have it. they have a service you can use for free to test. second option is going to the speaker in the bottom right corner of you screen on your desktop right click on this and go to recording device. if it doenst say a mice is plugged in that might be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check inside your Steam settings that your mic is being detected. If not it could be a problem with your line in. Try going into your Steam Settings and into voice and detect devices. Make sure that your microphone is set to both your default device and also your default communications device. Otherwise it mightn't be detected by Steam.